# Sorting strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to sort strings in javascript containing comma separated values in different e.g.

```
var Str = "8,0,2,10"
```

I want to sort it like below example form the last one to first one:

```
var NewStr = "10,2,0,8"
```

Comment: this is not string, not even array

Comment: And it’s not sorting; it’s reversing.

Comment: @Rajesh That’s really not a good dupe target. There’s a chance that the title will cause even more confusion (it’s impossible to change strings in-place in JS), and that question asks for reversing strings character by character, rather than splitting the string on commas, reversing that, then joining it again.

Comment: I'm aware and i'm looking for more apt solution, however if you read properly, only thing missing is the use of delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert string to array using `split()` and reverse the array element using `reverse()` and then convert result to string again using `join()` like this:

```
var Str = '8,0,2,10';
var dif = Str.split(',').reverse().join(',');
console.log(dif);
```